# WCF-TransportWithMessageCredential The HTTP request is unauthorized with client authentication scheme 'Anonymous'

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, authentication, iis

I'm trying to configure WCF authentication with UserName but without success, I have tried a a lot of solution that I found already, but nothing seem to work for me.

> The HTTP request is unauthorized with client authentication scheme
>   'Anonymous'. The authentication header received from the server was
>   'Negotiate,NTLM,Basic realm="localhost"'.

Server setting

```xml
<system.serviceModel>
<bindings>
  <wsHttpBinding>
    <binding name="basicHttpBindingConfiguration">
      <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential">
        <message clientCredentialType="UserName" negotiateServiceCredential="false" />
        <transport clientCredentialType="None" />
      </security>
    </binding>
  </wsHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<services>
  <service name="Namespace.Service" behaviorConfiguration="wsHttpBehavior">
    <endpoint binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="basicHttpBindingConfiguration" name="Soap" bindingNamespace="/WebServices" contract="Namespace.IService">
    </endpoint>
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpsBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" name="mex" />
  </service>
</services>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="wsHttpBehavior">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
      <serviceCredentials>
        <userNameAuthentication userNamePasswordValidationMode="Custom" customUserNamePasswordValidatorType="UserNamePasswordValidator, WebApplication" />
        <!--<serviceCertificate findValue="ServiceModelSamples-HTTPS-Server" storeLocation="LocalMachine" storeName="My" x509FindType="FindBySubjectName" />-->
      </serviceCredentials>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
</system.serviceModel>
```

On the client side

```xml
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
        <wsHttpBinding>
            <binding name="Soap">
                <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential">
                    <transport clientCredentialType="None" />
                    <message clientCredentialType="UserName" />
                </security>
            </binding>
        </wsHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
        <endpoint address="https://localhost:85/WebServices/Service.svc"
            binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="Soap" contract="ServiceReference1.IService"
            name="Soap" />
    </client>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Here is my IIS config
[image]

Most of solution that I found use Windows Transport, I need Authentication only through Username.

I check this :

- https://blog.sandervanlooveren.be/posts/securing-a-wcf-service-with-username-and-password/
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/samples/ws-transport-with-message-credential

I have tried security **mode="Message"** and security **mode="TransportWithMessageCredential"** without success

My client code look like :

```
 // Instantiate the proxy  
 var  proxy = new ServiceClient();

 proxy.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "username";
 proxy.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = "password";
```

Please can anyone check my config and tell what I'm setting wrong ?

Edit:
This is a Service inside an ASP.Net MVC5 App, Can this also be a problem ?

Answer (score 0):

There might be something amiss with the **customUserNamePasswordValidatorType** property string.It is usually in the following form

```
customUserNamePasswordValidatorType="Namespace.MyCustUserNamePasswordVal,Namespace"
```

Can you access the WSDL of hosting service? Also, turning on the anonymous authentication is enough, unnecessary to enable others authentication.
Here is my configuration, I used simplified configuration which be supported in WCF4.5, wish it is useful to you.

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
          <serviceCredentials>
            <userNameAuthentication customUserNamePasswordValidatorType="WcfService1.CustUserNamePasswordVal,WcfService1" userNamePasswordValidationMode="Custom"/>
          </serviceCredentials>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <bindings>
      <wsHttpBinding>
        <binding>
          <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential">
            <message clientCredentialType="UserName"/>
          </security>
        </binding>
      </wsHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <protocolMapping>
      <add binding="wsHttpBinding" scheme="https" />
    </protocolMapping>    
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
```

Feel free to let me know If there is anything I can help with.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. 
for customUserNamePasswordValidatorType, i think it's ok here customUserNamePasswordValidatorType="Namespace.MyCustUserNamePasswordVal, AssemblyName" .  I have this now  <userNameAuthentication userNamePasswordValidationMode="Custom" customUserNamePasswordValidatorType="WebApplication.UserNamePasswordValidator, WebApplication" />.  for the Question, Can you access the WSDL of hosting service? Yes i can. May be i have to added this information also. My app is not a WCF only Application. It's an ASP.MVC 5 app that i added a WCF SOAP Service. Can this be a probleme ?

Comment: Why does it prompt us that it uses basic authentication? 
By default, the WCF service application requires anonymous authentication is enough when authenticating the client with Username/password. Try to forbid the other authentication mode.
Besides, it works well with Asp.net MVC project when service use TransportwithmessageCredential security mode, I could post my code if you need.