# How to add user/pass authentication in WCF

Tags: c#, wcf

I want to add some security to my `WCF` application service. I figured out how to add username/password authentication:

```
<system.serviceModel>
  <behaviors>
    <serviceBehaviors>
      <behavior name="MyBehavior">
        <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="false" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
        <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
        <serviceCredentials>
          <userNameAuthentication userNamePasswordValidationMode="Custom" customUserNamePasswordValidatorType="Changer.Service.Validation.ServiceAuthenticator, Changer.Service"/>
        </serviceCredentials>
      </behavior>
    </serviceBehaviors>
  </behaviors>
  <bindings>
    <wsHttpBinding>
      <binding name="MyBinding">
        <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential">
          <message clientCredentialType="UserName" />
        </security>
      </binding>
    </wsHttpBinding>
  </bindings>
  <services>
    <service name="Changer.Service.Request.RequestService" behaviorConfiguration="MyBehavior">
      <endpoint address="/" binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="Changer.Service.Request.IRequestService" bindingConfiguration="MyBinding" />
    </service>
  </services>
</system.serviceModel>
```

This is my custom data validation:

```
public class ServiceAuthenticator : UserNamePasswordValidator
{
    public override void Validate(string userName, string password)
    {
        // Check the user name and password
        if (userName != Authentication.Providers.Service.PasswordChanger.UserName || 
            password != Authentication.Providers.Service.PasswordChanger.Password)
        {
            throw new System.IdentityModel.Tokens.SecurityTokenException("Unknown username or password.");
        }
    }
}
```

Unfortunelly I am getting error which is because I have no valid certificate. I tried following this tutorial:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/how-to-configure-an-iis-hosted-wcf-service-with-ssl

But without success. It says, that certificate hosts is not matching site url I am visiting. On client side I am getting error:

```
Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel with authority 'foo'. The underlying connection was closed: Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel. The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure
```

I can solve this by adding to my client app:

```
System.Net.ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += delegate { return true; };
```

Which is basically not solving my problem.. What can I do with that? I just want to have simple user/pass authentication.

I decided to get rid off `SSL`, then my code changed to:

```
<system.serviceModel>
  <behaviors>
    <serviceBehaviors>
      <behavior name="MyBehavior">
        <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="false" />
        <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
        <serviceCredentials>
          <userNameAuthentication userNamePasswordValidationMode="Custom" customUserNamePasswordValidatorType="PasswordChanger.Service.Validation.ServiceAuthenticator, PasswordChanger.Service"/>
        </serviceCredentials>
      </behavior>
    </serviceBehaviors>
  </behaviors>
  <bindings>
    <wsHttpBinding>
      <binding name ="NewBinding">
        <security mode="Message">
          <message clientCredentialType="UserName"/>
        </security>
      </binding>
    </wsHttpBinding>
  </bindings>
  <protocolMapping>
    <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https" />
  </protocolMapping> 
  <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
</system.serviceModel>
```

And after that I got this error:

```
Error: Cannot obtain Metadata from http://localhost:53705/R.svc If this is a Windows (R) Communication Foundation service to which you have access, please check that you have enabled metadata publishing at the specified address. For help enabling metadata publishing, please refer to the MSDN documentation at www.WS-Metadata Exchange Error URI: http://localhost:53705/R.svc Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved: 'http://localhost:53705/R.svc'. Content Type application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8 was not supported by service http://localhost:53705/R.svc. The client and service bindings may be mismatched. The remote server returned an error: (415) Cannot process the message because the content type 'application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8' was not the expected type 'text/xml; charset=utf-8'..HTTP GET Error URI: http://localhost:53705/R.svc The HTML document does not contain Web service discovery information.
```

So I decided to add `services` tag to my `web.config` next to `bindings`

```
<services>
  <service name="PasswordChanger.Service.Request.RequestService" behaviorConfiguration="MyBehavior">
    <endpoint address="/" binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="PasswordChanger.Service.Request.IRequestService" bindingConfiguration="NewBinding" />
  </service>
```

And I got another error:
`The service certificate is not provided. Specify a service certificate in ServiceCredentials.`

Comment: try changing this line in your settings file

<serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="false" httpsGetEnabled="true" />

to 

<serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="false" />

Comment: @ClaytonC Still same problem

Comment: Do you want/need SSL? If not you should follow [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/how-to-use-a-custom-user-name-and-password-validator) tutorial.

Comment: @mm8 I dont get these ms guides, because in most cases they never work. I added some more info to the thread containing what is written in link you shared.

Answer (score 0):

Whether we use the message security or transport layer security mode, we all need to provide a certificate to ensure that the username/password authentication mode is secure.
I have made an example related transport security mode.  we need provide a certificate to ensure that the service is hosted successfully.

```
    <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
          <serviceCredentials>
            <userNameAuthentication customUserNamePasswordValidatorType="WcfService1.CustUserNamePasswordVal,WcfService1" userNamePasswordValidationMode="Custom"/>
          </serviceCredentials>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <bindings>
      <wsHttpBinding>
        <binding>
          <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential">
            <message clientCredentialType="UserName"/>
          </security>
        </binding>
      </wsHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <protocolMapping>
      <add binding="wsHttpBinding" scheme="https" />
    </protocolMapping>    
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
```

If we don’t have a certificate, we could generate a self-signed certificate by using IIS Server Certificate Tool.
[image]
[image]
then we add https binding in the IIS website binding module so that the WCF service is hosted successfully.
[image]
**Custom Authentication class.** Based on the actual situation, configure this authentication class in the configuration file above.

```
    internal class CustUserNamePasswordVal : UserNamePasswordValidator
    {
        public override void Validate(string userName, string password)
        {
            if (userName != "jack" || password != "123456")
            {
                throw new Exception("Username/Password is not correct");
            }
        }
}
  <serviceCredentials>
            <userNameAuthentication customUserNamePasswordValidatorType="WcfService1.CustUserNamePasswordVal,WcfService1" userNamePasswordValidationMode="Custom"/>
          </serviceCredentials>
```

**Client.**

```
//for validating the server certificate. 
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += delegate
              {
                  return true;
              };
            ServiceReference2.Service1Client client = new ServiceReference2.Service1Client();
            client.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "jack";
            client.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = "123456";
```

if we use the message security, we could set up the certificate by the following code.( Configure your actual certificate according to the actual situation)

```
<serviceCredentials>
            <serviceCertificate storeLocation="LocalMachine" storeName="My" x509FindType="FindByThumbprint" findValue="869f82bd848519ff8f35cbb6b667b34274c8dcfe"/>
            <userNameAuthentication customUserNamePasswordValidatorType="WcfService1.CustUserNamePasswordVal,WcfService1" userNamePasswordValidationMode="Custom"/>
          </serviceCredentials>
```

Refer to the below link.
[WCF-TransportWithMessageCredential The HTTP request is unauthorized with client authentication scheme 'Anonymous'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55817544/wcf-transportwithmessagecredential-the-http-request-is-unauthorized-with-client/55825828#55825828)
[WCF UserName & Password validation using wshttpbinding notworking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55860810/wcf-username-password-validation-using-wshttpbinding-notworking/55898986#55898986)
Feel free to let me know if there is anything I can help with.